# Transformando uma variavel double em factor

Tags: r, variáveis, conversão-de-tipo

Olá,

Estou tentando converter uma variavel do tipo `double` em `factor`

```
ppar$abor <- as.factor(ppar$abor)
```

Mas estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, abor, value = integer(0)) :
```

Comment: Não é possível saber o que está causando o erro sem [uma amostra dos seus dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Rode `dput(ppar)` (ou dput(head(ppar)) se o data.frame tiver muitas linhas) e cole a saída na pergunte. Ou simplesmente forneça uma amostra dos valores da coluna abor.

Comment: As variáveis do tipo `double` são variáveis contínuas. Tem a certeza que quer converter em categórica? (Qual é a diferença entre as categorias `1.0`, `1.001` e `1.000000001`?)

Comment: Outra coisa, a mensagem de erro está incompleta, diz só que há um erro na função `$<-.data.frame` mas falta o erro em si. O que é que dizia logo a seguir?